# ssh-add with valid RSA key fails

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, rsa

I'm attempting to add an SSH key to the existing `www-data` user on Ubuntu 18.04.

`$HOME` for `www-data` is `/var/www` and the key lives in `/var/www/.ssh`

Permissions for `.ssh` are `700`

The key is `epp_deploy` and is chmod'd to `600`

running `file epp_deploy` returns `epp_deploy: PEM RSA private key.

All commands are being run as `www-data` via `sudo -u`

So, the file exists, it's in the correct location, has the correct permissions and it's a valid file in UTF-8 encoding. (NOT UTF-8-BOM)

And yet, when I run `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` then `ssh-add epp_deploy` from the directory, I get `Error loading key "epp_deploy": invalid format`.

Why?

If the file has proper permissions, is the correct format and the proper encoding, then why would the SSH agent still fail to read/add the key?

Comment: `file` only looks at enough of the content to make a reasonable guess at type, it doesn't fully check the format. Try `openssl rsa <epp_deploy` and see if that can read it without error.

Comment: Doesn't load:
> "unable to load Private Key
[################]:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY"

Comment: Then look at _exactly_ what is on the first line with `sed -n 1l epp_deploy` (that's one, ell); if you have 'comments' before the key (permitted but rare) adjust the number as needed. It must be five hyphens, the words `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` in uppercase separated by one space, five more hyphens, and a line terminator (either LF or CRLF, shown as `$` or `\r$`).